# Trigger handle multiple inserts

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've got a trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tgr_incheck_vlucht
ON PassagierVoorVlucht
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
IF @@ROWCOUNT= 0 BEGIN RETURN END
SET NOCOUNT ON
BEGIN TRY
IF EXISTS 
     (SELECT *
     FROM inserted I
     WHERE EXISTS(SELECT *
                  FROM PassagierVoorVlucht P inner join Vlucht V on    P.vluchtnummer = V.vluchtnummer
                  WHERE I.inchecktijdstip >= vertrektijdstip))
BEGIN
RAISERROR('Inchecktijdstip moet voor de aankomsttijdliggen', 16,1)
END
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 BEGIN ROLLBACK TRANSACTION END   
    DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000) = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
            @errorSeverity INT = ERROR_SEVERITY(),
            @errorState INT = ERROR_STATE()
    RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage, @errorSeverity, @errorState)
END CATCH   
END
```

now i have written some test statements:

```
INSERT INTO PassagierVoorVlucht
VALUES(850, 5316, 1, '2002-01-01 13:37:00.000', 21),
(1002, 5316, 1, '2004-01-01 13:37:00.000', 21),
(1601, 5316, 1, '2004-05-01 13:37:00.000', 21),
(1602, 5316, 1, '2004-05-01 13:37:00.000', 21)
```

the trigger works for only ONE insert row at the time not for the whole block. How can i write the trigger that it can handle multiple inserts?

Comment: What do you mean "handle multiple inserts"? Do you want the error to be raised four times?

Comment: No, the first two insert values row are good and must be inserted, the last two insert values rows are false and must be rollback. But now it inserts nothing. I hope you understand it.

Comment: Well, you are checking if *any* row violates your business logic, and rolling back everything. You might consider an `INSTEAD OF` insert trigger, where you can insert only the rows that *don't* violate your business logic.

Comment: Or...use a stored proc and standardize your database logic. Triggers fire after code is compiled and can be disabled. In contrast, stored procedures are designed for this kind of logic on a grand scale, centralize administration of inserts, can be optimized, provide easy monitoring, and follow the "simplest solution" method that will save yourself in the future.

Comment: @clifton_h The problem is that many people are pro-"SQL code in app code," adamantly against stored procedures (whether due to valid reasons or brain-washing). And stored procedures can easily be bypassed, especially in environments where security is less rigorous. In general, I trust that a trigger will have better odds at enforcing business logic (e.g. not be disabled) than a stored procedure (which can't truly be enforced as the only DML path).

Comment: @clifton_h Now, don't get me wrong, I'm all for stored procedures, and that is probably a decent solution for a large portion of environments. I just don't think they're sufficient for *all* environments. It's possible the OP has already chosen a trigger precisely because of valid reasons that aren't relevant to the question.

Comment: @Aaron.Bertrand then by golly the OP should include these details. Fundamentally, triggers are responses, and they can be disabled or elevated to do damage to a database. If your proc is altered, your system is compromised, whereas Triggers are a lot easier to find and disable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is you cannot... Fundamentally, triggers are fired for *each insertion*, not a batch of code. This is why it is called a trigger, or a response.

Furthermore, if your table had an Insert Identity column, triggers will not prevent gaps in the rows since they function just like sequences are: activated at the row level and after the statement completes (unless INSTEAD OF).

Perhaps helpful in explaining triggers is the following from MSDN:

> [CREATE TRIGGER (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx)
>
> Although a TRUNCATE TABLE statement is in effect a DELETE statement, it does not activate a trigger *because the operation does not log individual row deletions*. However, only those users with permissions to execute a TRUNCATE TABLE statement need be concerned about inadvertently circumventing a DELETE trigger this way.

Notice the part about individual row deletions as well as the point about scope. Perhaps understanding more what your requirements are might make the solution clear.

Now, you may use an `INSTEAD OF` trigger to fire before the attempted code executes, but that likely is not going to be a solution, unless you had some staging table setup or similar for it to function.  Instead of replaces the entire DML or DDL statement.

- If you wish to protect the integrity of your data consider the use of stored or pre-planned procedures.
- If that is unacceptable or impractical, other constraints like referential keys or even staging tables (depending on the need for the timeliness of data) which can later be imported could be options.

Answer (score 1):

To do this you need to use a temporary table inside your trigger and store all the inserted data in it and then loop that table using a while loop.
here is an example where we want to add all the inserted users into a audit table using a trigger for insert

```
alter trigger tr_userData_forInsert
on userData
for insert
AS
BEGIN
declare @id int, @name varchar(20)   

select *
into #inserted_data 
from inserted

while ( exists(select id from #inserted_data) )
begin
    select top 1 @id = id, @name = full_name 
    from #inserted_data

    insert into loggs
    values ( concat( 'a user with ',@id, ' and name of ', @name
    , ' is added at ', getdate() ) )

    delete from #inserted_data
    where id = @id
end
end
```

I already used this in more than one situation and it work perfect

Comment: doesn't work, error while creating trigger:

"Cannot use text, ntext, or image columns in the 'inserted' and 'deleted' tables."